# Angular2+ redirectTo route not working

Tags: angular, angular5

When my web app loads in the browser, my address bar shows "localhost:5000". It does not load/redirect to my "faq" page but displays an empty page. I can't seem to think of any reason why this happens. There is no console error. Can anyone help? [Snapshot of my console output is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzWpV.png)
My route configuration is below:

```js
RouterModule.forRoot(
      [
        {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: '', component: GeneralComponent,
children: [
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './thrive-home/thrive-home.module#ThriveHomeModule'},
  { path: 'resources', loadChildren: './thrive-resources/thrive-resources.module#ThriveResourcesModule'},
  { path: 'services', loadChildren: './thrive-services/thrive-services.module#ThriveServicesModule'},
  { path: 'profiles', loadChildren: './thrive-profiles/thrive-profiles.module#ThriveProfilesModule'},
  { path: 'chat', loadChildren: './chat/chat.module#ChatModule'},
  { path: 'user', loadChildren: './thrive-user/thrive-user.module#ThriveUserModule'},
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactUsComponent},
  { path: 'faq', component: FaqComponent },
  { path: 'privacy-policy', component: PrivacyPolicyComponent},
  { path: 'confirm-email', component: ConfirmEmailComponent },
  { path: 'book-appointment', component: BookAppointmentComponent }
]
  },
        ],{ enableTracing: true })
```

Comment: please add console output also.

Comment: Try This `RouterModule.forRoot(
      [
        
        { path: 'faq', component: FaqComponent },
        { path: 'privacy-policy', component: PrivacyPolicyComponent},
        { path: 'confirm-email', component: ConfirmEmailComponent },
  {path:'', redirectTo:'/faq', pathMatch:'full'},
        { path: '**', component: PrivacyPolicyComponent }
        ],{ enableTracing: true })`

Comment: This made no difference

Comment: Please Check the `<base href="/">` is added  in `index.html`

Comment: yes <base href="/"> is already added.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `/` in the redirect to url, and place it after the defined routes (e.g. before `**`).

Also ensure that in your `app.component.html` file you have a `<router-outlet>`, and that you are importing your `AppRouterModule` in your `AppModule` imports list.

Comment: `**` should always come at last since it match all routes

Comment: @N.HariHaraSudhan I said before `**`, by defined routes I meant routes with a fully defined path (e.g. `faq` or `confirm-email`)

Comment: sorry i didn't noticed that.

Comment: @JosephAfriyieAttakorah if you navigatye to a url e.g. `localhost:5000/faq` does it work?

Comment: @JosephAfriyieAttakorah can you post a stackblitz showing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `/`

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
      [
        {path:'', redirectTo:'faq', pathMatch:'full'},
        { path: 'faq', component: FaqComponent },
        { path: 'privacy-policy', component: PrivacyPolicyComponent},
        { path: 'confirm-email', component: ConfirmEmailComponent },
        { path: '**', component: PrivacyPolicyComponent }
        ],{ enableTracing: true })
```